# When to use a Dataset?

Tags: c#

I'm new to programming and got stuck trying to understand the use of of a Dataset in a multiuser environment.
What I don't understand is:

- If user A pulls data to a DS and user B make changes to the DB, are the changes going to be updated on user A's DS before they also make changes?
- Is there any other way to directly interact with the DB without using a Dataset if an answer to the above is No?

Comment: No, the rows on the DataTable associated to the DataSet belonging to user A are not updated. [This doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.common.dataadapter.update?view=netframework-4.8) explains the elaborated process that happens when you try a DataAdapter.Update passing a Dataset with modified rows

Comment: Are you using Entity framework?

Comment: "I'm new to programming" and  "When to use a Dataset?" : probably never. This is old technology, consider skipping it.

Comment: I think this article will help you: [Optimistic Concurrency](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/optimistic-concurrency)

Comment: @HenkHolterman That comment would be a lot more useful if it recommended what could be used as a less-old replacement.

Comment: Thanks to everyone. What's the best way in respond to my last question?

Answer (score 2):

Datasets are used for in Memory databases of ado.net see here in detail:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/ado-net-datasets

Datasets have better Performance on queries and data modificatons.

DataSet is a disconnected orient architecture that means there is no need of active connections during work with datasets. So to answer first part there will be no update between different datasets. Here is it a weekness and you must write back as soon as possible.

We can load a single Table from the database into a DataTable and manipulate the data in memory and write result back.

Example:

```
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace workingwithdataset
{
    public partial class frmdataset : Form
    {
        public frmdataset()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        private void frmdataset_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SqlDataAdapter dadapter = new SqlDataAdapter(" select * from student_detail ", " database=student;user=sa;password=wintellect ");
            DataSet dset = new DataSet(); //Creating instance of DataSet
            dadapter.Fill(dset,"student_detail"); // Filling the DataSet with the records returned by SQL statemetns written in sqldataadapter
            dataGridView1.DataSource = dset.Tables["student_detail"]; // Binding the datagridview
        }        
    }
}
```

Also you can use sql script:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/tutorials/scripting-ssms?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: See also here 'access through datasets': https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/dotnet/net-framework/should-you-use-ado-net-datareader-or-dataset/amp/